# wordpress - all pages are blank except the home page

Tags: wordpress

My site works fine. I have a development copy that was working fine but now all pages apart from the home page are blank. The files are identical on both servers, apart from the wp-config.php and the .htaccess files. I tried removing the theme and the plugin folders to no avail. I'm lost now! What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried looking for errors in the web server's error log, or enabling `display_errors` in php.ini or .htaccess to see if an error is being thrown?

Comment: Yes. Nothing logged... BUT I just trigged an error when trying to access wp-settings.php: `require(ABSPATHwp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream` Obviously ABSPATH is not defined. But I don't know how to fix it. Strangely this happens on both copies of the site, and one of them still works fine?!

Comment: The fact that a literal `ABSPATH` appears fused onto `wp-includes` implies either that there is mangled syntax somewhere, which PHP is silently correcting into an invalid file name (the line should look something like `require(ABSPATH . '/path/to/file');` -- pay special attention to balancing the quotes and using `.` for string concatenation) or that the ABSPATH actually is not being defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after hours and hours, changing the permalinks to 'default' and then back to the right setting (in my case Post name) solved my problem.
I hope this helps someone in the future.
I still don't know why I get a strange ABSPATH error message though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem working on a website hosted at Bluehost. Everything beyond homepage was white.

**The solution was to move the contents of my sub-directory into /public_html.**

Despite this article to the contrary (https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/347), Bluehost support told me the primary domain cannot be run from a sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its same case, i had same issue with other pages and after i updated plugin "Wordfence Security" everything works now. So the issue was there, because i had Disabled automatic-update for that plugin.